# Read zip files from hdfs and create a dataframe with file name and file content

Tags: zip, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read zip files located in wasp location and, creating a df with the file name and file content. Rach zip file is having multiple .rcv files.

I tried doing it but it's giving the content of all files as an rdd, and not exactly how I want it.

the below code gives the zipfile name and its files contents as key value pair. what i expect is to have to the individual file name and its content as key value pair

eg:
ACARS 20170507/file1.rcv "file content as string"

ACARS 20170507/file2.rcv "file content as string"

```
def zip_extract(x):
    in_memory_data = io.BytesIO(x[1])
    file_obj = zipfile.ZipFile(in_memory_data, "r")
    files = [i for i in file_obj.namelist()]
    return dict(zip(files, [file_obj.open(file).read() for file in files]))


zips = sc.binaryFiles("hdfs://ACARS 20170507.zip")
files_data = zips.map(zip_extract).collect()
```

Comment: May we see what code you are working on? This seems to be rather unclear at present.